# Debug executable with arguments in IDA

Tags: linux, ida, disassembly

In the disassembler and debugger IDA, is there any way to run the currently loaded binary with command line parameters? For instance, say I have the command `/bin/ls` and want to debug it as `/bin/ls test.txt`, how could I do that in IDA?

Comment: I've searched the Internet for an answer, and can't find anything! The best I could find was a forum where a user asked this question, and then was rudely instructed to do some Google-ing on his own first, before asking! Not very helpful...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to the `Debugger` / `Process options...` menu item and fill the `test.txt` argument in the `Parameters` field.

The path to the executable (including the binary) will be in the `Application` field.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I need! Now, hopefully, this will be an easier question to Google for!